# Forcing arrow function to re-evaluate expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

I have a React app, and in one of its files I have some util functions. 
One of them is an arrow function looks something like this:

```
export const getSomeData = () => {
    const cookieValue = <LOGIC_TO_READ_SOME_VALUE_FROM_COOKIE>;
    return cookieValue;
};
```

The problem is that arrow functions are being evaluated just a single time: once the page is initially loaded. 
So the result is that this function is evaluated to some concrete value and remain that value until next page refresh. 
If the value of the cookie changes, I will still get the previous value since the code in the arrow function will not run again.
However, if I switch to standard ES5 JS function, of course I will not encouter that problem: the code will run each time the function is invoked.

Is there a way to "force" arrow function to re-evaluate its returning value?

Comment: No, that function will run again **every time it's called**. If you're seeing it return the same value, that means the code within it ran again and found the same value, not that it didn't run again. It sounds like the cookie value **isn't** changing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder agreed. If `getSomeData` is called again, it should run the `<LOGIC_TO_READ_SOME_VALUE_FROM_COOKIE>` block again. Perhaps that logic returns stale values?

Comment: *"However, if I switch to standard ES5 JS function, of course I will not encouter that problem"* No, I'm afraid that's simply incorrect. The format of the function doesn't matter, arrow vs. `function` vs method. They all run each and every time you call them.

Comment: Using an arrow function instead of ECMAScript2015 style should not make that kind of difference, assuming the browser supports ES6 syntax.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Just wanted to add that although the format of the function does not matter to it getting executed, the only difference is in the interpretation of `this` inside block and arrow functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the result is that this function is evaluated to some concrete
>   value and remain that value until next page refresh.

**No!**

Arrow functions wouldn't do that.

```
setInterval(()=>{console.log(Math.random())}, 1000)
```

You would see that the above statement generating a whole range of random values at one-second interval.

It is only that your code inside the arrow function generate the same result.